# Convert int to NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nstimer

I'm making a game in Swift and I want the sprites to move faster as the time passes.

I have a variable that increases in every second (It works with an `NSTimer`). I want to replace the duraton with this variable, in this line of code:

```
let action = SKAction.moveToY(120, duration: 3)
```

But I can't because the duration must be of type `NSTimeInterval`.

How can I transform my variable (which is Int) to NSTime Interval so it can work properly?

Comment: no, it works properly with just 3. But what I want to do is have a variable as duration, the variable is of type int, how do I transform this variable so it can be in duration?

Comment: Why not use `NSTimeInterval` for the variable instead of `int`?

Comment: And how do I transform my variable to NSTimeInterval?

Comment: typecasting is prohibited by law? =D

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is a wrapper of `double`. Just cast the `int` variable to `double`

Comment: or just declare that variable as `NSTimeInterval`. both should work

Comment: I do that, and when i put the variable in duration I get an "use of unresolved identifier" error

Comment: I figured it out, I had the variable outside the function, it's ok guys, thanks anyways

Answer (score 6):

NSTimeInterval is defined as:

> typealias NSTimeInterval = Double

So, technically, you can define your interval and assign direct integers:

```
var interval: NSTimeInterval = 3
```

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote here. OP said the issue was that NSTimeInterval variable was defined outside the scope. What I have suggested makes sense to the context here.